# HTML background video not loading

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML background video only loads when I click before the site fully loads. I have the site live here: https://skyr0.cc/

```
<video id="bgvidhh" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
  <script>
    var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
    video.volume = 0.1;
  </script>
  <source src="files/bgvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: It auto plays for me in chrome (Version 72.0.3626.96 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Answer (score 0):

I can only play the video if I allow an 'unsafe connection' for loading 
in Google Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official build) (64-bits)
Firefox does not block your video background by default.

Please send some more information about the other JS scripts you are loading
and their order.
Some of your scripts might be making an http-request which is considered unsafe.
Deeper inspection is hard since the console and source code are disabled..